# How to fix this NullPointerException on executeQuery?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I Have a NullPointerException on the executeQuery of my simple sql statement; I think the problem come from the connection to sqlite but i cant figure it out...

My java method :

```
    public Connection connect() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:sakila.db.sqlite3";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM FILM LIMIT 10";
    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    return conn;
}
```

And this is the result from the console

```
Connection to SQLite has been established.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
at Connect.connect(Connect.java:33)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hrmm... Have you tried debugging? Most of the time, for this type of error, people find it with debugging. On a side note, it looks like you are not handling the `NullPointerException` exception in your catch block. Add a catch block for it where it's needed.

Comment: @Sometowngeek You generally should not catch `NullPointerException` as usually it is an indication of bugs in your code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I thought *Exception e* is the one you want to avoid.

Comment: @Sometowngeek NullPointerExceptions are usually a sign of bugs that need to be fixed, catching them is ignoring those problems and should be avoided. Don't catch NullPointerException, but fix the underlying cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you're closing connection right before using it. Try to move statement + executeQuery inside the try-catch

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the sqlite Statement implementation. A situation like this should throw a `SQLException` with a 'connection is closed' (or `statement is closed` or similar) message.

Answer (score 5):

Your finally block, closes the connection, so when the statement

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

is reached, it will throw a NullPointerException. To fix the problem, your code should look like this:

```
public Connection connect() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:sakila.db.sqlite3";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM FILM LIMIT 10";
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        } finally {  
            try {  
                if (conn != null) {  
                    conn.close();  
                }  
            } catch (SQLException ex) {  
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());  
            }  
        }
    }
```